# See AdMob revenue individually for each app

Tags: google-analytics, admob, revenue

Is there a way I could see my revenue split down on to each app I have? I am very curious about which of my apps generate the most revenue, but AdMob only displays the total revenue made that day. I can not use Analytics because I have not implemented the SDK into any of my apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement google analytics.

In the admob console, click the `Monetize` tab. Once you're there you can filter apps or adunits and select a particular date range to view your earnings:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, don't know how could have I overlooked that